# suddenly getting SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

Hi I am using the following code to send mail:

```
function send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
    {       
//echo "enter mail";    
        require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;  
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP(); 
        //$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
        $mail->Port       = 465;             
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
        $mail->Username="xxxx";  
        $mail->Password="xxx";            
        $mail->SetFrom('xx@gmail.com','xx');
        $mail->AddReplyTo("xx@gmail.com","xx");
        $mail->Subject    = $subject;
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);
        $mail->Send();
    }
```

what i have done so far: i have checked the error log but nothing in it,i have also changed the port but that also not working.

The website is hosted in a server,the above code was working fine until tomorrow,i suddenly start getting the error.I don't have access to the `php.ini` file .Pls help.any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what have you done so far to solve the problem?

Comment: You're using an old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on an obsolete example. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and read the docs.